# Door hard to open and close after new carpet

Tags: carpet

We just have our new carpet but now door has become very hard to open and close. Cutting the door isn’t a option as it’s expensive made door. What other ways are there to make the opening and closing of door easy?

Comment: A carpenter will be able to modify any wooden door without degrading its appearance. Steel doors are a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace the door hinges with [Rising Butt Hinges](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Rising-Right-Handed-Hinge-Stainless/dp/B01GO858KI/ref=sr_1_3_sspa?crid=3D69NBPB62ITB&keywords=lifting%20hinge&qid=1563823559&s=gateway&sprefix=lifting%20hi%2Caps%2C126&sr=8-3-spons&psc=1), these cause the door to lift up by about 10mm as it is opened. They have the side effect that the door wants to "fall" back to the closed position as if a spring is gently pushing it. If you generally want to leave the door open, you will need to use a door-stop or a wedge to hold it open against the force.

Comment: great, only concern is if I take off hinges what if I cannot put them back as labour isn't cheap in uk

Comment: A valid concern - I live in the UK myself so I know whereof you speak. If you are going to do it yourself then you definitely need to make sure the Rising Butt Hinges that you buy are exactly the same *pattern* as the hinges you are replacing; same size (all 3 dimensions) and same hole spacing. In theory, you should be able to just swap them directly.

Comment: That is tricky knowing what to buy that will match

Comment: Depending on the door frame clearance, the door or the frame may still have to be modified to allow for the vertical movement of the door. Granted this will likely be less modification, but it's still a possibility.

Answer (score 5):

After a bit of time depending on its construction, the carpet will begin to fray with some use. This wear will make the door even more difficult to open and close due to the catching of threads on the door material if it's wood, say.

Try removing the carpet underlay material from the area near the doorway so the surface of the carpet is slightly lower than it was. Unfortunately, this will decrease the lifespan of the carpet due to loss of some shock absorbance.

Check that the bottom of the door is free from any burrs, screws, trim, or splinters that may interfere with opening and closing. Planing a few millimetres from the door bottom leading and trailing edges will help and won't be noticeable.

If the original flooring was wood parquet, there's a chance a couple of the tiles are slightly higher than their neighbours which would very slightly increase the average height.

Finally, ensure that the door is parallel to the floor surface.

If none of these suggestions work for you, the alternative is to choose between modifying the door or a different decorative treatment than a carpeted doorway.

Good luck.